# cakephp save from select field

Tags: cakephp

i have these models,**Teacher** and **FormsStream** with association defined as this
**Teacher Model**

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'FormsStream' => array(
    'className' => 'FormsStream',
    'foreignKey' => 'stream_head',
    )
);
```

**FormsStream Model**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Teacher' => array(
    'className' => 'Teacher',
    'foreignKey' => 'stream_head',
    'fields' => array('teacher_id','designation','last_name')
    );
```

**i have the same kind of association between the FormsStream Model and another model which works fine**.

**Problem**

cakephp cant save **teacher** from a **select list**.the teacher id is passed fine.i know this since i can see it passed in my proxy but i cant seem to figure out why it cant save.

**FormsStream Controller(how am fetching the list of teachers) for both add and Edit methods**

```
$teachers = $this->FormsStream->Teacher->find('list',array('fields' => array('last_name')));
$forms = $this->FormsStream->Form->find('list',array('fields' => array('form_name')));
$this->set(compact('forms','teachers'));
```

The forms from the above code saves fine and it has the same associations defined as teachers.

Answer (score 0):

never mind. solved it though if to ask..must cakephp foreign key associations have the same names as the columns they reference? because changing the name is what solved my problem